# how to set child Div with 100vw of device width when parent div having width :80vw

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css

```css
.parent {
  width: 80vw;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.child {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

How can I align center a child `div` when parent `div` having lesser width then `child`? How to set child `div` with `100vw` of device width when parent `div` having width `80vw`?

Comment: Hi Yogesh. I'm a little confused on what you're trying to achieve. Will there parent be 1024px whilst the child is 100% of the screen? It sounds like you might need a different structure whereby you have a parent div that's 100% of the screen, then two children. One that's 1024px and one that's 100%. Am I understanding this correctly?

Comment: @ – MegaTron in above code, child div is overflowing towards right side, i would like to align child div  center to device width

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If this is what you're trying to do, center the parent, and then center the child using position relative, and a negative left value.

```css
.parent {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
  margin: 0 auto; /* center the parent in the screen */
}

.child {
  position: relative;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
  /* center the child using a negative left */
  /* left: calc(50% - 50vw); */
  /* or */
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: i want output like above, with out  left: calc(50% - 50vw); will not work in mobile browsers, i have tryied

Comment: @DVYogesh why not? There are other ways to center. I'll add another.

Comment: even i have tried transform: translateX(-50%); no use in mobile browsers, something looking fine

Comment: Try to isolate the problem, for example open stackoverflow in the mobile browser, and see if the example I've added works. If it does, you've got another problem in your css, html, etc...

Comment: @ Ori you have tried best yaar, cool working, you got up vote

Answer (score 1):

Just set `margin-left: -10vw;` in child element.

```css
.parent {
  width: 80vw;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
  margin:auto;
}

.child {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
  margin-left:  -10vw;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```